# Javascript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would be very grateful if someone would be able to help me make this document work:

http://pastebin.com/f3E7PQe5

- So that only A-Z characters can be entered in the 'First and last name' & 'please enter your marital status' input box's.
- So that only numbers 17 and above can be entered in the 'Please enter your age' input box.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running into a specific issue? You aren't going to find a lot of people here willing to do your work for you.

Comment: Also, there is almost always a better alternative than `document.write`. Look into `document.createElement`, `document.getElementById`...

Comment: yes, I have no clue where to begin with doing this (new to javascript) everything I have tried doesn't seem to work, or works for one but breaks the other.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give ya the general direction you should be able to work this one out. I nested the if statements just to visualize it better. You could also add else clauses that alert the appropriate error.

It just makes sure age > 17, and first and last name are only characters, then calls quote.

```
 //give your form an ID 
document.getElementById("form").submit(function(){
  if (userAge > 17){

     if ( firstName.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/) === -1 ){
         if ( lastName.search(/[^a-zA-Z]+/) === -1) {
            quote()
         }
     }
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response man, just tried this method and cant seem to get it working.